# Different versions of Same Django App

Tags: django, facebook

This is a design question. My goal is the following:

The Django webapp corresponds to a website. I want that website to be accessible through its official domain, but also from inside Facebook.

However, if the user is inside Facebook, I want the application to use a different template folder which has "lite" versions of all the templates.

On a first iteration my team accomplished this by URL:
- url.com would take you to the page rendered with the normal template
- url.com/?fbapp=true would take you to the page rendered with the lite template

Now, my question is, what is the best method to detect the app is being run on Facebook in order to define the templates?
- URL parameter like above is a way, in my opinion a bad way;
- Some session variable (but this could be bad, as one person navigating app in both Facebook and the site in same browser would get the same template type for both)

There should be something that allows me to distinguish between when a person accesses my site, url.com, and when they access it through the Facebook app.

Can somebody help?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, get parameter does not look like the most elegant but still works (as far as you remember to keep it in place).

One way to solve this can be to run the app on two different root urls, eg.

/ matches the 'regular' app

/facebook/ matches the root for the app with FB templates

Then you just need to use a different settings file for facebook app and there set something like

```
USE_LITE_TEMPLATES = True
```

Or even change the root path of templates and handle the whole facebook thing w/o touching a line of code in the views :)

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I am looking for. However, considering you run a project (not an app), and a project has only one settings file, how do I run two versions of the same project with different settings?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook includes your site via iframes, so as far as your site is concerned, there is no difference between being embedded in Facebook versus directly being accessed. What you've done already (appending a query string) is as sensible as any approach.